# setCompoundDrawableWithIntrinsicBounds is not drawing anything...but only sometimes

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am creating some buttons programatically, I am adding the buttons this way:

```
final Button btn = new Button(this);
                    btn.setText(array.get(i));
                    btn.setTextSize(10);
                    btn.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.white));
                    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            goToModule(texto);
                        }
                    });
                    btn.setHeight(height);
                    btn.setWidth(width);
                    btn.setOnTouchListener(parentListener);
                    btn.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,getDrawableForText(texto),null, null);
                            btn.setPadding(0,35,0,0);
                            btn.setBackground(gd);
                            btn.setLayoutParams(params);
                        }
                    });

                    row1.addView(btn);
```

Up to 19 buttons can be drawn. They are inside a ViewFlippers, so the user can page between pages

The getDrawableForText method:

```
private Drawable getDrawableForText(String texto) {
    Drawable drawable=null;
    if(texto.equalsIgnoreCase("Viajes")){
        Log.i("LOG", "This drawable is the problematic one");
    }
    if (texto.equals(textosBotones[0])) {
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.vuelo,getTheme());//Viajes

    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[1])) {
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hotel,getTheme());//Hotel

    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[2])) {
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.agenda,getTheme());//Agenda
        /*int h = btn.getHeight()-100;
        int w = btn.getWidth()-100;
        drawable.setBounds( 0, 0, w, h );
        Bitmap icon= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.agenda);
        Bitmap newbitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon,w,h, true);
        dr = new BitmapDrawable(EventActivity.this.getResources(), newbitMap);*/

    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[3])) {
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ponentes,getTheme());//Ponentes


    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[4])) {
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.documentos,getTheme());//Documentos


    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[5])) {
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ubicacion,getTheme());//Ubicaciones


    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[6])) {
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.contactos,getTheme());//Contactos


    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[7])) {
        //drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.preguntas,getTheme());//Encuestas
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.valoracion,getTheme());//Encuestas/valoraciones

    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[8])) {
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.qr,getTheme());//Distintivo/best business


    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[9])) {
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.info,getTheme());//Forum

    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[10])) {
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.galeria,getTheme());//Galería


    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[11])) {
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chat,getTheme());//Chats


    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[12])) {
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.muro,getTheme());//Muro


    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[13])) {
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.asistentes,getTheme());//Asistentes


    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[14])) {
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.twitter,getTheme());//Twitter


    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[15])) {
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.twitter,getTheme());//Facebook


    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[16])) {
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.twitter,getTheme());//Instagram


    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[17])) {
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.qr,getTheme());//QR


    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[18])) {
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.valoracion,getTheme());//Proveedores


    } else if (texto.equals(textosBotones[19])){
        /*drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.trophy,getTheme()));
        DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, getColor(R.color.white));*/
        /*drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.trophy,getTheme());
        Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, getColor(R.color.white));
        drawable=wrappedDrawable;*/
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actividad, getTheme());//Actividades
    }else if(texto.equals(textosBotones[20])){
        drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.noticias,getTheme());
    }else{
        Log.i("LOG", "Something weird happened");
    }
    return drawable;
}
```

The first time I enter this Activity, the drawable is drawn correctly. BUT, if I click one of the buttons (which goes to another Activity), and inside that new Activity, I click on a Button that goes to a third Activity, if I go back to the main Activity(where the buttons are) there is one drawable that is not drawn, its always the same, the first one. Th rest of the drawable of the rest of the buttons are drawn ok.

The main Activity is not recreated again, it remains in memory. Anyway, if I draw it again, the same weird behaviour happens.

I am pretty lost, since the third Activity is not affectin the first one in any way.

Someone could guide me about what is happening?

Thank you.

PD: If you need further details, please let me know.

EDIT:

In third Activity, I am doing something like this:

```
private void getArrivalsFromJSON(String resp) {
    arrivals=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrivalModel all=new ArrivalModel();
    all.setDestination("");
    all.setTerminal("ALTTODO");
    all.setType("");
    arrivals.add(all);
    try {
        JSONObject json=new JSONObject(resp);
        JSONArray data=json.getJSONArray("data");
        for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++){
            JSONObject obj=data.getJSONObject(i);
            ArrivalModel arrival=new ArrivalModel();
            arrival.setDestination(obj.getString("destination"));
            arrival.setTerminal(obj.getString("terminal"));
            arrival.setType(obj.getString("type"));
            arrivals.add(arrival);
        }
        generateLayout();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

In thath for, if I modify the line:

```
for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++)
```

and change it like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<data.length()-7;i++)
```

The button drawable it is drawn normally! I have checked in the Android Studio profiler, and it is never using more than 90Mb of RAM. It is too much?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. Was not related with memory, or other performance issues.

What was happening is, in the third Activity I was using the same .png I was using in the button, but I was changing its color:

```
d.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.parseColor(color), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
```

So, when I was going back to the first Activity, and tried to draw the Drawable, it was drawing, but with its color changed. Given that the button color, and the color I was changing the drawable with was the same, it appeared that the drawable was not being drawn; it fact it was being drawn, but was not visible.